# Combination of the present perfect and the simple past?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, present-perfect, descriptive-grammar

Is there a chance to combine these two tenses this way, *I **have checked** with several sites, and I **found out** that it's seemingly some jobless old latino, definitely not Willis.*

Comment: Who or what is *willis*?

Comment: Bruce Willis, the Hollywood actor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 'combination' of tenses here, just a coordination of main clauses. Main clauses in coordination are permitted different tenses.

Comment: What if I omit the second *I*? Can it be called a combination of tenses? Does it make any difference in sense?

Comment: There'd be a different level of coordination. If the second _I_ is left out it would be ambiguous as to whether the coordination was for _I_ + (A) _and_ (B) or _I have_ + (A) _and_ (B) as both would make sense since _found_ is both preterite and past participle of _find_. You could force the former interpretation by having the second coordinated element start with _did find_. Any way you cut it though, it still ends up being a coordination of clauses where _I_ plays subject to both.

Comment: Thanks a lot DW :)

Answer (score 1):

This is completely acceptable. This usage is normal--you might catch any normal American combining the sentences this way. With this being said, I think it would be most normal for this combination to be used in answering a question.

**I have checked** --> The person speaking has completed an action that perhaps they were asked about: ("*Did you check?*") or perhaps if someone else was accusing them of not having checked: ("*Why didn't you check?*").

**I found out** --> The person speaking is letting the person asking know what they found out.

If the person speaking is volunteering the information, or bringing up the topic, it would be more natural to say: "**I checked** *with several sites, and **I found out** that it's seemingly some jobless old Latino, definitely not Willis.*"